# I can't get my form data into an array to display in a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, html-table

I have a webpage with a form on it for entering patient information (all dummy data of course). I set up the form and a table to display the information that is submitted. I just can't seem to figure out why the data is not getting stored in the array when the user clicks the "Add Patient" button. I have attempted to submit data multiple times and then I used "console.log(patientArray)" to check the array, and it says that the information I attempted to store is undefined.

This is my web page:

```
@using OnboardingProject.App_Code
@using OnboardingProject.Controllers

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Patients";
}

<div class="title">
    <div>
        <h1 style="float: left">@ViewBag.Title</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="rmm" style="float: right; display: inline-block">
        <ul>
            <li><button id="NewPatient">New Patient</button></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="modal_content">
    <div id="modal_window" title="Complete the form below to add a new patient:">
        <div style="text-align: right;"><a id="modal_close" href="#">close <b>X</b></a></div>

        <form id="add_patient" method="POST" action="#" accept-charset="UTF-8">
        <p><label>First Name<strong>*</strong><br>
        <input type="text" autofocus required size="48" id="fname" value=""></label></p>
        <p><label>Last Name<strong>*</strong><br>
        <input type="text" autofocus required size="48" id="lname" value=""></label></p>
        <p><label>Birthdate (mm/dd/yyyy)<strong>*</strong><br>
        <input type="text" autofocus required size="48" id="bday" value=""></label></p>
        <p><label>Site Name<strong>*</strong><br>
        <input type="text" autofocus required size="48" id="location" value=""></label></p>
        <p><label>SSN<strong>*</strong><br>
        <input type="text" autofocus required size="48" id="pat_ssn" value=""></label></p>
        <p><input type="button" value="Add Patient" onclick="addPatient()"></p>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="content">
    <div id="patient_table">
        <table id="patients">
            <tr>
                <th id="p_name">Patient Name</th>
                <th id="p_site">Site</th>
                <th id="dob">Date of Birth</th>
                <th id="ssn">SSN</th>
                <th id="edits"></th>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/PatientInfo.js")" type="text/javascript></script>
```

This is my javascript file:

```
//Display the modal when New Patient button is clicked
$("#NewPatient").click(function () {
    $("#modal_window").show();
});

//Hide the modal when close is clicked
$("#modal_close").click(function () {
    $("#modal_window").hide();
});

//Create an array to store Patient Information
var patientArray = [];

var fName = document.getElementById("fname").value;
var lName = document.getElementById("lname").value;
var bDate = document.getElementById("bday").value;
var sName = document.getElementById("location").value;
var SSN = document.getElementById("pat_ssn").value;

function addPatient( fName, lName, bDate, sName, SSN ) {
    patientArray.push(fName, lName, bDate, sName, SSN);
    $("#modal_window").hide();
}

//Create a table from the array
var table = document.getElementById("patients");

var tbody = document.createElement("tbody");
table.appendChild(tbody);
patientArray.forEach(function (items) {
    var row = document.createElement("tr");
    items.forEach(function (item) {
        var cell = document.createElement("td");
        cell.textContent = item;
        row.appendChild(cell);
    });
    tbody.appendChild(row);
});
```

Comment: You are trying to get the values when page loads, before user can even interact with the elements. Also if code is run in head, the elements themselves won't even exist without using a load handler.

Comment: the code isn't run in the head. The call to the script file is done at the bottom of the html file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The html button calls the function addPatient(). Note that calling the addPatient function has got nothing to do with executing the previous five lines (outside the function) , which is where the values are getting picked up into the variables. That's why, when the function is called, nothing happens. Also, the function expects 5 parameters in its definition. Then you must call the function with 5 parameters. Or put the act of picking up the values, inside the function, and calling with no parameters.

In other words, here are the two ways :
**Option 1 :**

Move this code inside the function addPatient. 
Remove the parameters definition for the function and make it a function with no parameters.

```
var fName = document.getElementById("fname").value;
var lName = document.getElementById("lname").value;
var bDate = document.getElementById("bday").value;
var sName = document.getElementById("location").value;
var SSN = document.getElementById("pat_ssn").value;
```

**Option 2 :**

Keep the addPatient function as it is. But, make another function, say, Fetch_And_Add_Patient() that has the following code :

```
function Fetch_Add_Patient() {
    var fName = document.getElementById("fname").value;
    var lName = document.getElementById("lname").value;
    var bDate = document.getElementById("bday").value;
    var sName = document.getElementById("location").value;
    var SSN = document.getElementById("pat_ssn").value;
    addPatient(fName, lName, bDate, sName, SSN);
}
```

And then in the HTML button, call the above function, without any parameters, instead of calling addPatient without any parameters.

```
<p><input type="button" value="Add Patient" onclick="addPatient()"></p>
```